# Getting list index by matching strings list of lists

Tags: python, python-3.x

`p = [['a','b','c'],['x','y','z']]`

How can I get the list index containing the string(char) 'a'?

'a' in list doesn't work, or at least I can't figure it out.

Comment: You have list inside a list. Which list's index do you want?

Comment: `print([i for i, v in enumerate(p) if "a" in v])` ?

Comment: can the nesting be arbitrary and not fixed to depth=2?

Answer (score 1):

use `in` but in the sublists, not in the global list of lists. Combined with `enumerate` to get the index of the matching list(s)

```
p = [['a','b','c'],['x','y','z']]

idx = [i for i,sublist in enumerate(p) if 'a' in sublist]
```

that gives you a list of indexes. Here we have only one element:

```
>>> idx
[0]
```

You can use the same technique to compute the index of `a` in the sublist BTW (with `idx = [i for i,sublist in enumerate(p) if 'a' in sublist]`)

To get a sole value or `None`, just iterate once on a generator comprehension:

```
idx = next((i for i,sublist in enumerate(p) if 'a' in sublist),None)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
list_count = 0
for x in list:
   list_count += 1
   if 'a' in x:
       print ("Index in sublist" %(x.index('a')))
       print("Index of outer list" %(list_count))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set the maximum nesting depth to 2 you can use the following code to get both indices.

```
p = [['a','b','c'],['x','y','z']]

def get_indices(p, search_for='a'):
    return [(i, sublist.index(search_for)) for i,sublist in enumerate(p) if search_for in sublist]

print('a', get_indices(p, search_for='a'))
print('b', get_indices(p, search_for='b'))
print('c', get_indices(p, search_for='c'))
print('x', get_indices(p, search_for='x'))
print('y', get_indices(p, search_for='y'))
print('z', get_indices(p, search_for='z'))
print('k', get_indices(p, search_for='k'))
```

output:

```
a [(0, 0)]
b [(0, 1)]
c [(0, 2)]
x [(1, 0)]
y [(1, 1)]
z [(1, 2)]
k []
```